Maps JavaScript APIを試したところ、エラーが出る
プログラミング初心者です。
Maps JavaScript APIを使って、都市の名前がついたボタンを押すと、map内でその場所に移動し、マーカーがささるといったwebサイトを作ろうとしたところ、実行はできたのですが、コンソールで以下の3つのエラーが出ました。github copilot等を使っても解決しません。原因のわかる方がいたら、エラーの出ない方法を教えてほしいです。
3つのエラー

you have included the Google Maps JavaScript API multiple times on this page. This may cause unexpected errors

Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'xn')

Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'Fg')


index.tsx
import { useEffect, useState } from 'react';

declare global {
  interface Window {
    initMap: () => void;
  }
}

type MapLocation = {
  name: string;
  lat: number;
  lng: number;
};
const locations:MapLocation[] = [
  { name: '東京', lat: 35.6811673, lng: 139.7670516 },
  { name: '大阪', lat: 34.6937378, lng: 135.5021651 },
  { name: '名古屋', lat: 35.1814511, lng: 136.9065574 },
  { name: '福岡', lat: 33.5903548, lng: 130.4017151 },
  { name: '札幌', lat: 43.061771, lng: 141.354451 },
];

export default function Home() {
  const [map, setMap] = useState<google.maps.Map | null>(null);
  useEffect(() => {
    if (!window.google) {
        window.initMap = function() {
          const mapElement = document.getElementById('map');
          if (mapElement) {
            const initialMap = new google.maps.Map(mapElement, {
                center: { lat: locations[0].lat, lng: locations[0].lng },
                zoom: 15,
              });
              setMap(initialMap);
          }
    };
    const script = document.createElement('script');
    script.src = `https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=map_api&callback=initMap`;
    script.defer = true;
    script.async = true;
    document.head.appendChild(script);
    }
  }, []);

  const handleClick = (location: MapLocation) => {
    if(map) {
      map.setCenter(new google.maps.LatLng(location.lat, location.lng));
      new google.maps.Marker({
        position: new google.maps.LatLng(location.lat, location.lng),
        map: map,
        title: location.name,
      });
    }
  };

  return (
    <div>
      <div id="map" style={{ width: '100vw', height: '70vh' }}></div>
      {locations.map((location, index) => (
        <button key={index} onClick={() => handleClick(location)}>
          {location.name}
        </button>
      ))}
    </div>
  );
}


「you have included the Google Maps JavaScript API multiple times on this page. This may cause unexpected errors」このメッセージに書いてあることが原因だったりしませんか？

最初の問題は、こちら「https://stackoverflow.com/q/9719157/7949528」にある問題と同じではないでしょうか？
